# Classifying singularities using limits

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

I'm attempting to classify the singularities of $f(z) = z^3e^\frac {1}{z}$ using limits, as I haven't learned how to find Laurent expansions yet. To show that the function has an essential singularity at $z=0$ I need to find a sequence that makes the limit finite and one that makes it approach infinity. I found one to make it approach infinity, but I'm struggling to come up with one to make it finite. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: A sequence....converging to **what** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

$$z_n:=\frac in\implies |f(z_n)|=\left|-\frac i{n^3}e^{-ni}\right|=\frac1{n^3}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\;?$$